# VHDL Hierarchical Configuration

Tags: vhdl

I'm trying to change the mapping of a library primative from unisim to unifast in my design, but only for simulation purposes. I want to specify the configuration at the testbench level.

My design hierarchy looks something like this:

```
entity m1_chip_tb is
end m1_chip_tb;

architecture behavioral of m1_chip_tb is
    ...
    m1: entity work.m1_chip
        m1_clocks: entity work.clock_logic_m1
            mmcm_pix: MMCME2_ADV
```

All the examples for doing VHDL configurations (including the ones on Xilinx's site) that I've been able to find seem to assume the configuration applies to a entity instantiated locally. But I need a configuration that drills down from the top testbench level.

Here's what I've tried using:

```
configuration cfg_xilinx of m1_chip is 
    for rtl
        for m1:clock_logic_m1
            use entity work.clock_logic_m1(rtl);
                for rtl
                    for all:MMCME2
                        use entity unifast.MMCME2;
                    end for;
                end for;
        end for;
    end for;
end cfg_xilinx;
```

But I get an error "Cannot find component declaration" on the m1: line

Incidentally, the entire design is written using instantiation by entity with the exception of the MMCME2_ADV instantiation.

I'd appreciate any suggestions for how to properly specify the hierarchy in the configuration definition.

(As a point of clarification, I have the unisim libary specified in the clock_logic_m1.vhd file. I'm trying to override that for my simulations); i.e.:

```
library unisim;
use unisim.vcomponents.all;
```

Comment: You are instantiating entities, not components. To use configurations you must declare and instantiate components.

Comment: You also need an m1_chip_tb configuration declaration to provide a binding indication to your m1_chip configuration cfg_xilinx to avoid a default binding in simulation. Synthesis will want either the m1_chip configuration or a default binding indication (in which case you could do just an m1_chip_tb configuration that reaches down to all MMCME2s for simulation).

Comment: @RenaudPacalet - Does this mean that everything in the hierarchy all the way down to the MMCME2 must have a component declaration?

Comment: @Barry Moss - Absolutely. If you use entity instantiations you do not need configurations. Configurations are used to bind instantiated components to existing entity/architecture pairs (plus, optionally, configuring the generic parameters). So, you must chose between instantiating entities and using configurations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use configuration with direct instantiation - that is the main drawback. However, if you don't insist on using configuration for the control, you can use propagated generics or have constants in a shared package to achieve what you want:

```
g_MMCM_RTL : if gGeneric_or_cConstant generate
    mmcm_rtl : [entity library.]MMCME2_ADV
. . .
end generate g_MMCM_RTL;

g_MMCM_SIM : if not gGeneric_or_cConstant generate
    mmcm_sim : [entity library.]MMCME2
. . . 
end generate g_MMCM_SIM;
```